# How do I query a columns data type in access 2003?

Tags: sql, ms-access, lua, sqldatatypes, luasql

I am looking for a way to get the data type of a column given the table that it is in and the name of the column.  I have seen other answers refer to the MSysIMEXColumns table but my Access database does not have that table. I am using Access 2003 if that helps any.

I would like to get the result into my LUA code as a hash table so that before inserts or lookups I can look up the data type of column. Basically it's so that I can determine if field needs quotes around it or not.

LuaSQL is being used to access the access database.

Any help or direction is appreciated

Comment: Are you looking to get the result in code? If yes - where is this code running; what language? If no - please clarify.

Comment: @G.Stoynev I edited it to include this information

Comment: Are you using [LuaSQL](http://www.keplerproject.org/luasql/) to connect to the database?

Comment: @GordThompson Yes I am

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LuaSQL `cursor object` documentation [here](http://www.keplerproject.org/luasql/manual.html#cursor_object) suggests that you should be able to use

```
cur:getcoltypes()
```

to return "a list (table) of column types".